# After refreshing website jquery stops working

Tags: jquery

Essentially when I initially insert the code it works fine but when I refresh the page it stops working, anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
$('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
    $('.nav-icon').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```
<title></title>
```

`>

Comment: What errors can you see in the console?

Comment: Where is the ending tag of </script>

Comment: can you please provide the markup

Comment: JS does not automatically store the state of the page—regardless of whether the class is toggled or not, when you refresh the page the state is lost. You will have to consider storing the toggle status as a cookie, or in localStorage.

Comment: I can't seem to get the code entered without getting an error message back on StackOverflow so I attached it as an image instead. I hope that is helpful.

Comment: There is the icon where you can format the code correctly—highlight your code block, and click the `{}` button. Do not attach an image that has code that you want to troubleshoot. If you do not know how to format your post correctly, attach the code anyway and I will format it for you.

Comment: Appreciate the help guys, apologies for myself being so useless. gskemna below has remedied the problem, i'm going to do a little more research on jquery as to try and not run into these kind of issues. appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is executed before DOM nodes are parsed/processed (because your script comes before `<body>`). To fix this, you should execute your code after the DOM has been parsed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.nav-toggle').on('click', function () {
    $('.nav-icon').toggleClass('active');
  })
});
// YOu can have this both at the top and the bottom
```

Another way is to move the script to the bottom of `<body>` which is a common and recommended practice. If you do, you don't really need to wrap it in `$(document).ready`, because yhr DOM nodes are parsed and then your script is parsed - all in correct order. For more infor on recommended practices, see: [html5boilerplate.com](https://html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: beat me to it.
wrap your script with $(function () { <script>YOUR SCRIPT</script> })

Comment: That's perfect, it's completely fixed the issue

Comment: Thank you so much, would there be any readable books or sources that would help with this kind of stuff in the future?

Comment: Just study the HTML5 boilerplate for starters, google `html5 boilerplate explained`.